# Use custom font in GitHub pages

Tags: css, github, github-pages

Trying to change the font in `styles.css` file in GitHub pages, here is the code:

```
  @font-face {
      font-family: "Samim";
      src: url("/resources/Samim.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
```

Here is the directory and font saved in resources folder

[project files directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l30dn.png)

the problem is that font doesn't change, also tried to move the font to main directory but no change, it also works properly locally on vscode live preview.

Comment: you need to add the code here!

Comment: What has this to do with Github?

Comment: @Aahad did you mean html code?

Comment: @match it works well locally but when commit new changes to GitHub it doesn't  work on online GitHub pages!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the **Relative Path** to the file,

For Example Take This Directory Structure:

```
- root
  - system-files
  - vahid
    - github-pages
      - resources
        - Samim.ttf
      - README.md
      - index.html
      - styles.css
```

Here the **"root"** is the Drive On which your Operating System is Stored On, and **"system-files"** contains your Operating System's Important Files and finally you have this folder **"vahid"** which contains the user's files, and inside **"vahid"** you have **"github-pages"** folder where all your github pages code is stored.

In Path the `/` means the **root**, in Windows take this as like if you open `C:\` in Windows Explorer.

And this period `.` means current directory, and when you use `./` instead of `/` you're specifying a path to a file/folder in **current Directory**.

Now when in my `styles.css` if I use this Path `/resources/Samim.ttf` what it means is "Samim.ttf" File in inside of the **"resources"** folder in the **root** directory.

Did you notice something? Let me try to show this path in the directory Structure.

```
- root
  - resources
    - Samim.ttf
```

As you can see the Path we specified doesn't exist, try to compare it to the Real Directory Structure Given Above.

So instead of using `/` we have to use `./` because the **"resources"** folder is in the same folder as of the **"styles.css"**.

So you have to replace your **Absolute Path** with **Relative Path**, which will be this:

- `./resources/Samim.ttf`

Read More About **Relative** And **Absolute** Path At [LinuxHandBook.com](https://linuxhandbook.com/absolute-vs-relative-path/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the directory path like this:

```
url("./resources/Samim.ttf")
```

just added one `.` after `/`, idk why but it works now!

also trided `../resources`  , `..resources` and `/resources` and didn't worked.